# What purpose does Bran serve by still greenseeing into the past?

Tags: character, game-of-thrones

In episode 8.04 (*The Last of the Starks*) of *Games of Thrones*, the story continues to march along with the characters continuing to prepare for the future by playing 'The Game of Thrones',

> as none of them really discuss how this all happened and with the
>  belief that the Night King and/or the threat of the White Walkers has
>  been resolved.

But Bran mentions to Tyrion that he now spends most of his time in the past.

But if this was really the case,

> that The Night King, The White Walkers, and by extension the Azor Ahai 
>  prophecy has been fulfilled or is now inconsequential,

then why is Bran spending so much time in the past NOW?

**Besides this being a possible clue about those *other things*, is there any other logical reason why he would be doing this?**

---

**To Better Explain:**

And while I'm well aware of the following exchange:

> Bran Stark: Yes, he will. He'll come for me. He's tried many times
>   before, with many three-eyed ravens.
>
> Samwell Tarly: Why? What does he want?
>
> Bran Stark: An endless night. He wants to erase this world, and I am
>   its memory.
>
> Samwell Tarly: That's what death is, isn't it? Forgetting, being
>   forgotten. If we forget where we've been and what we've done, we're
>   not men anymore, just animals. [to Bran] Your memories don't come from
>   books. Your stories aren't just stories. If I wanted to erase the
>   world of Men, I'd start with you.

It does not answer the specific purpose of any given 3ER, except to say that his existence threatened the Night King; it does not answer why a 3ER is needed to be the world's memory!

At the heart of my question, I'm looking for this answer, because as it stands, the bigger threat seemingly has been lifted and Bran's knowledge has been used sparingly (and potentially destructively) and there is little evidence to support why either Bran or any 3ER would need to dwell in the past or if this is just a natural byproduct of being a 3ER? Is this what they all do, or does Bran have a choice about what he chooses to look at, and when?

Is he looking for something specific for a specific purpose that relates to the story we have left or his dwellings moot?

Comment: He's the three-eyed raven, the memory of the world, the history of the world contains more than just the night king and the white walkers...

Comment: Ok, but if he doesn't share much of it, why does that matter? What in the history of the world is left that would matter now??

Comment: I mean, everything, even Jon's true lineage was important, and he shared with Sam. I agree he is kind of useless, but it's clear why he spends so much time in the past...

Comment: It was clear why, but no longer IMO. What information is out there that would impact the story we have left? That's why I'm asking.

Comment: I'd wager the present is dull and boring for someone who can view all the momentous occasions through out history at their whim.

Comment: Bran has been looking into the past ever since he became the Three Eyed Raven. When he talked about spending so much time in the past, he wasn't simply referring to the time that's passed from when the Knight King was killed to that current moment in time. If you spend eight hours a day for several years practicing piano in a room, and you then take one day off, you'd still refer to yourself as someone who spends most of their time alone in a room playing piano.

Comment: At the same time, just because the Knight King threat is neutralized that doesn't relieve Bran of his duty being the Three Eyed Raven.

Comment: @Charles again maybe, but why? Why do we need someone to preserve the history of the world in this way?  What good is it?

Comment: @DarthLocke What good is archiving records in general? Most companies have some form of a retention policy for their data, even though most records will never be pulled. At the same time, threats to the Realm aren't restricted to those beyond the Wall, so perhaps the knowledge of the Three Eyed Raven will be used again in the future when other events transpire. IMO, the Three Eyed Raven is like a one person Citadel in this regard (but with much more invasive methods), with Archmaester Ebrose saying that the Citadel is the memory of the Realm.

Answer (score 2):

The context of that conversation was that after the war Bran would be Lord of Winterfell. But that kind of future holds no interest to what Bran has become.

The Three-Eyed Raven has lived so many lives that he doesn't have any personal desires (or other emotions) anymore. He remembers being Bran the same way he remembers being any previous incarnation of the Three-Eyed Raven.

In fact, in episode 2 we learned that the Three-Eyed Raven's role is to be the "memory of the world". Being the memory of anything requires living in the past.

Comment: But that doesn't exactly answer why knowing the memory of the world is relevant, when the big threat has seemingly been taken care of and when his family is falling apart. So far his knowledge has been used minimally (granted Aegon is a big impact) and so it's hard to see what the point is and/or if there is any SPECIFIC reason he is sifting through the past NOW? There are theories that the 3ER was created for the purpose to combat TNK! If that was true, then his purpose seems to have been served...